# How can I split/substract an integer by 100 in php

Tags: php

Given an integer is 310 I want this integer to be splited like this

While storing in array it should be like this.

```
arr[0] = 100;
arr[1] = 100;
arr[2] = 100;
arr[3] = 10;
```

Edit: I knew how to use array_fill but I need a solution without using built in function like array_fill

Comment: Provide informations on what you have done so far ... Research, code ... anything.

Comment: ``$num = 310; $array = array_fill(0,(int)$num/100,100); $array[] = $num%100;`` something like this : )

Comment: `array_fill()` is a good solution; why can you not use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple function can help you break any values into the number of pieces of your desired value.

```
<?php

$input = 310; // 100, 100, 100, 10

/**
* Breaks the number into summable pieces of array
* @param $input int
* @param $pcsvalue int
* @return $pieces array
* Eg. 
* $input = 310 
* $pcsvalue = 100 
* will be broken into 100, 100, 100, 10 
* or some other given piece value.
* final output = array(100, 100, 100, 10)
*/
function breakNumberIntoSmallPieces($input = 0, $pcsvalue) {
    $pieces = array();      
    if($input > 0) {
        $breakintovalueof = $pcsvalue;

        while(($op = $input - $breakintovalueof) > 0) {
            $pieces[] = $breakintovalueof;
            $input = $op;
        }

        $pieces[] = 100 + $op; // added into final op value because final op might be in negative value
    } else {
        $pieces[] = $input;
    }

    return $pieces;
}


$result = breakNumberIntoSmallPieces($input, 100);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 100
    [3] => 10
)
```

Another short and sweet solution is:

```
<?php
    $input = 310;
    $pcsvalue = 100;

    $pieces = [];
    $remainder = $input % $pcsvalue; // returns 10
    $times = (int) ($input / $pcsvalue); // returns 3 by converting 3.1 to 3
    $i = 1;
    while($i <= $times){ // add 100 3 times into array
        $pieces[] = $pcsvalue;
        $i++;
    }

    if($remainder) {
        $pieces[] = $remainder;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($pieces);
?>

Output:

Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 100
    [3] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using array_fill:

```
$num = 310;
$slash = 100;
$array = [];
$mod = $num%$slash;
for($i=0;$i<(int)($num/$slash);$i++){
    $array[] = $slash;
}

if($mod) {
    $array[] = $mod;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: (now even negative numbers are welcome!)

```
<?php
function breakTheNum($number, $breakWith = 100) {
    $float = $number / $breakWith;
    $count = floor($float);
    $outarr = array();
    if($count > 0) {
        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
            $outarr[] = 100;
        }
        $outarr[] = ($float - $count) * $breakWith;
    }
    elseif($count < 0) {
        for($i=0; $i>$count+1; $i--) {
            $outarr[] = -100;
        }
        $outarr[] = ($float - ($count+1)) * $breakWith;
    }
    else {
        $outarr[0] = $float * $breakWith;
    }

    return $outarr;
}

    $array = breakTheNum(334);
    print_r($array);
?>
```

the result:

```
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 100 [2] => 100 [3] => 34 )
```

for example `breakTheNum(-534)`:

```
Array ( [0] => -100 [1] => -100 [2] => -100 [3] => -100 [4] => -100 [5] => -34 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your real problem ,on some assumption i am providing some code what you may use

```
<?php
$arr=array();
$num=310;
while($num>=100)
{
    array_push($arr,100);
    $num=$num-100;
}
array_push($arr,$num);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped in a function something like this

```
<?php
    $number = 310;
    $splitAmount = 100;

    $splittedArray = splitNumberInArray($number, $splitAmount);
    var_dump($splittedArray);

    function splitNumberInArray($number, $splitAmount) {
        $returnArray = array();
        while($number > 0) {    
            if($number < $splitAmount)
                $splitAmount = $number;
            $number -= $splitAmount;
            array_push($returnArray, $splitAmount);
        }
        return $returnArray;
    }

    /*
         result: 
         array (size=4)
             0 => int 100
             1 => int 100
             2 => int 100
             3 => int 10
    */
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param $number
 * @param $step
 * @return array
 */
function break_into_peaces($number, $step) {
    $array = array();
    while($number >= $step) {
        array_push($array, $step);
        $number = $number-$step;
    }
    array_push($array, $number);
    return $array;
}

var_dump(
    break_into_peaces(334, 100) // 100, 100, 100, 34
);

var_dump(
    break_into_peaces(334, 50) // 50, 50, 50, 50, 50 , 50, 34
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested/fixed version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32612798/715329:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Utility;

use Webmozart\Assert\Assert;

class PaginationUtil
{
    /**
     * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32612798/715329
     */
    public static function breakLimit(int $limit, int $maxLimit): array
    {
        Assert::greaterThanEq($limit, 1, 'Limit should be 1+');
        Assert::greaterThanEq($maxLimit, 1, 'Limit should be 1+');

        $result = [];
        while ($limit > $maxLimit) {
            $result[] = $maxLimit;
            $limit -= $maxLimit;
        }
        $result[] = $limit;

        return $result;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Utility;

use App\Utility\ArrayUtil;
use App\Utility\PaginationUtil;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Webmozart\Assert\Assert;

class PaginationUtilTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     * @dataProvider breakLimitDataProvider
     */
    public function breakLimitTest(int $limit, int $maxLimit, array $expectedLimits): void
    {
        self::assertSame(
            $expectedLimits,
            PaginationUtil::breakLimit($limit, $maxLimit)
        );
    }

    public function breakLimitDataProvider(): array
    {
        return [
            /**
             * 1.0 Limit = maxLimit
             */
            [
                22,
                22,
                [22],
            ],
            [
                100,
                100,
                [100],
            ],

            /**
             * 2.0 Limit < maxLimit
             */
            [
                22,
                100,
                [22],
            ],

            /**
             * 3.0 Limit > maxLimit
             */
            [
                222,
                100,
                [100, 100, 22],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```